# Is this a pattern? If so, which one? (Contexts, Requests and Responses)

Tags: design-patterns

In most of my code nowadays, I adapted to an approach which I think I read in the context of "Clean Code". It was some years ago and I cannot find the source again, so I would like to know what the name of this pattern really is (and if it's even a pattern).

The approach is so simple, yet powerful that I am baffled as to how hard it is to find sources on this, but that might just be lack of proper search words.

The approach is, in order to write unit-testable code, to decouple the function and presentation of an application (duh) in such a way, that the two parts actually communicate via an interface which I always describe as "HTTP-Like".

That is, the functions your code can do are one project, and the display etc. are another project. The only communication between the two is done by using `Context` classes, which accept a `Request` and return a `Response` for anything your code can do.

So, e.g. if your code translates a sentence, you'd have a `TranslationContext`, along with the `TranslationRequest` (which has a property `text`) and the `TranslationResponse` (with a property `text` that includes the translated text).

The `Context` class is the only interface from your actual application code to the "outside", whereas the "view" is also seen as the outside.

From the presentation side, you' call

```
TranslationContext ctx = new TranslationContext(interfacedDbOrTextfile);
TranslationRequest req = new TranslationRequest("hallo welt");
TranslationResponse resp = ctx.Process(req);
Console.Write(resp.Text); // "hello world"
```

Additionally, any data sources (DB, Text files, etc) must be interfaced and decoupled when passed to the core, so you can always replace them with UnitTestable things like in-memory strings instead of textfiles or arraylists instead of database rows.

Is what I am describing just the application of known patterns in a way that I cannot see? Or is it a pattern which was not described yet? Or am I just using different words for things that already exist?

Comment: I think it is just providing arguments explicit instead of using implicit environment variables and similar. Also, `Dependency Injection` / `Inversion of Control` might be what you are searching for.

Comment: @valenterry It's exactly that *"just"* you are using that I want to get rid off. I have a hard time explaining this approach to colleagues because I don't have a proper name for it... I know DI - it's close, but not entirely what I am talking about. Will look into `Inversion of Control`, thanks.

Comment: Separation of concerns. n-tier. **Service-Oriented Architecture**, probably best overall.

Comment: @AakashM: Are context objects typical of SOA?

Comment: @RobertHarvey indeed not, but a service-oriented approach is what he's perhaps *aiming for* ("decouple the function and presentation of an application (duh) in such a way, that the two parts actually communicate via an interface"). Your answer is a good answer, as opposed to my throwaway comment.

Comment: This may be using multiple patterns, IoC probably one of them because services unknown to each other directly are interacting via a set of interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **[Context Object](http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/ContextObject.htm)** is a pattern used in a number of places, including J2EE, ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework.  It is used "to encapsulate state in a protocol-independent way to be shared throughout your application."

Context Object is a controversial pattern.  Although it can be thought of as a means of Inversion of Control or Dependency Injection, it's really more like a convenient way of passing the working environment around (akin to a "god object.") Context objects can be difficult to mock, therefore testability of the code that uses them is negatively impacted.

**Further Reading**
[Context Object](http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/ContextObject.htm)
[Passing around ginormous context objects](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/10/27/pass-around-ginormous-context-objects/)
[Mocking HttpContext](http://o2platform.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/mocking-httpcontext-httprequest-and-httpresponse-for-unittests-using-moq/)

Requests and responses are just message passing.

Comment: Interesting read, thanks. I can see how the `Context`s can become quite big. So far though, I don't think I slipped into the "God Object" antipattern, because I create many, many contexts and each is only doing a single, capsuled thing. Most of them are only around 100 to 200 lines long. Thanks for the links